# How to get the last step?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I try to interchange the integral and limit
$$\int_{c}^{\infty}f(y)dy=\lim_{k\to\infty}\int_{c}^{k}f(y)dy$$
why the last step holds? Why claims the last step using the Monotone convergence theorem?

Comment: The last step has nothing to do with MCT. Otoh the _first_ step uses MCT...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define $f_n(y)=\frac{1}{y^2+1}1_{[c,k]}(y)$

Note that $1_{[c,k]}(y) \to^{k \to +\infty}1_{[c,+\infty)}(y)$ pointwise.

and $1_{[c,k]} \leq 1_{[c,k+1]}$ so you can use the monotone convergence theorem since $\frac{1}{y^2+1} \geq 0$

> This is to answer the previous question,before you edited and changed it.

Comment: but how about then? How to integral that? It is just $\int_{c}^{\infty} \frac{dy}{1+y^2}dy$?

Comment: @TYG... Note that $\int 1_A(x)dx=\int_Adx$

Comment: Yes, I know. But without using MCT, I still have $\int_c^{\infty} f(y)dy$. Why should I write $\int_c^{\infty} f(y)dy=\int f(y)1_{(c,\infty)}dy$?

Comment: @TYG ...it is the same as my previous comment where $f(y)=1$

Comment: Yes. It is $\int f(y)1_{(c,\infty)}=\int_{(c,\infty)} f(y)dy$. But without MCT, I can integrate $\int_{(c,k)} f(y)dy$ directly. And then take the limit. Isn't it right?

Comment: @TYG yes it is...i just justified thinterchange of the integral and limit,since you mentioned monotone theorem.

Comment: So we can integrate it directly? It is not necessary to claim MTC, isn't it?

Comment: @TYG yes you can..